# 1D array vs 2D arrays printing strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know that to print a string, we use

```
char *pt = "Hi there";
printf("%s", pt);
```

or

```
char pt[] = "Hi there";
printf("%s", pt);
```

where the array name acts like a pointer referring to the address of the first element.

however when we get a 2D array for example, to print a string we have to dereference the array first before we can print the string.

```
char b[2][10];
strcpy(b[0], "banana");
strcpy(b[1], "apple");
printf("%s", *(b+1));
```

i am wondering why we have to dereference the array first before printing the string as in the first case we can print the string by giving the address of the char array to printf.

however in the second case we already have the address of the second string "apple" so why is it we have to dereference the pointer (b+1) first before we can printf the value inside?

Comment: You can write `printf("%s", b[1]);` since `b` is a 2D array, `b[1]` is a 1D array and it is just the same as your first example now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays in C are a bit subtle.  You are correct that `b` and `b[0]` both resolve to the same physical address, but they have different data types, which affects how pointer addition works for instance.  Also, note that `*(b+1)` is the same as `b[1]`.

The array `b` decays to type `char (*)[10]`, which is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`.  So if you add one to it, it adds `10 * sizeof(char)`.  But `b[0]` decays to type `char *`, so if you add one to it, it adds `sizeof(char)`.  The dereference doesn't actually translate to a memory operation, but acts more like a type cast.

Comment: Good answer, but rework *"The dereference doesn't actually translate to a memory operation, but acts more like a type cast."* as it is somewhat in conflict with the what the first sentence of that paragraph says. Kinda off. It does act in one way like a cast, but it is certainly a memory operation (a reference) as well. It provides a pointer to array of chars `type char (*)[10]` just as you say.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well the point is that no code is generated when going from `b` to `b[0]`.  The address is the same, but the type is different.  Remember, when accessing `b[i][j]`, a *single* memory load is performed, not two (just as with a one-dimensional array).  That's the point I was making.  This is in contrast to, for example, an array of pointers to `char`, which would require two memory loads to access.

Comment: That why I voted you up but dropped the comment. I know what you are saying, but I was trying to suss out a way that may not leave someone who doesn't know scratching their head saying "I am dereferencing, but its not a memory operation and it is more like a cast..?" That's perfectly true, but then it is also true that the dereference provides the value stored at the address, which in this case just happens to be the beginning of an array (in an array of arrays) in what is called a 2D array. I guess it's the 'not a memory operation' that gives the most heartache.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `b[0]` is not stored in memory, and it produces no code.  Remember, two-dimensional arrays are packed.  There are no pointers stored in memory.  They are very different from arrays of pointers, even though references to them are syntactically the same.  So `char x[2][10]` is a packed sequence of 20 `char`, but `char *x[2]` is an array of two `char *`, and `char **x` is a single pointer to a `char *`.  All three can be accessed as `x[i][j]`, but the first is a single load, the second is two loads, and the third is up to three loads (if `x` is in memory).

Comment: Every dererence is a load of another address or value. (of course we are taking about register loads the result of the dereference). I guess the overarching point to make is that every dereference provides a new address, type or value. The key is to know how the dereference behaves given the object at hand. Obtaining a pointer to the rows allows each row to be treated as a char array. Whether done by `b[0]` or by `&b[0][0]` the result is the same, but with the first you have a pointer to row, with the second you have a pointer to type. I guess it's a clear as it needs to be. Good job.